# REST API in python - the data never makes it back

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I am trying to get data from a server via REST API. I am expecting zip files toe be returned.

The exact same code works fine for smaller data (<1 MB zip files), but not when I request the larger data (it should be ~10 MB zip file).

```
s=req.Session()
res_data = s.get(myurl,
    headers={apikey},
    json = {somearguments}
)
```

The server log shows the request was completed on server side, but the code on my end is till running, 2 hours later.

Since the server log shows the GET request as completed, is it correct to assume that the problem is the route back ? If so, how can I track the problem ? If not, what might be the problem ?

Comment: Check on the API side if there is no request body size limit. Especially in the case of Node.js server.

Comment: could be a timeout issue. the requests library does not have a default timeout and will wait forever. if you pass a timeout parameter, you may learn more.

Comment: This bit me in the rear end once as well. It turned out in my case to be Nginx configuration only allowing less than 10mb of data to flow in or out. I had the exact same timeout you experience. So check any reverse proxy in the chain as well.

Comment: @Vishnudev other machines are able to download, even with the same apikey; so no request body size limit

Comment: @JustLudo - no clue how to do that...

Comment: So if other machines can download then it's got nothing to do with my previous solution. It's client sided and not server sided, otherwise others would have the same experience. Look into your own network details (firewall would be a nice place to start). Maybe virusscanner is blocking incoming connections?